# Android Studio shows the warning inotify limit is too low

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

Every time on start Android Studio displays a warning.

> The current inotify(7) watch limit is too low.

I don't understand what it is all about. Should I be worried about it ?
How to solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

According to the IntelliJ [documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Inotify+Watches+Limit),

> For an intelligent IDE it is essential to be in the know about any
> external changes in files it working with - e.g. changes made by VCS,
> or build tools, or code generators etc. For that reason, IntelliJ
> platform spins background process to monitor such changes.
>
> Inotify requires a "watch handle" to be set for each directory in the
> project. Unfortunately, the default limit of watch handles may not be
> enough for reasonably sized projects, and reaching the limit will
> force IntelliJ platform to fall back to recursive scans of directory
> trees.

Therefore, you need to add

```
fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 524288
```

in "/etc/sysctl.conf"

and then run the following command for it to take effect

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working, any other workaround to fix it.

Comment: Instead of adding a newline to /etc/sysctl.conf you should add a new file like /etc/sysctl.d/98-inotify.conf.  After rebooting or running sudo sysctl -p you can test you have the syntax correct with sysctl -a.

Answer (score 10):

Here's the clean and easy copy-and-paste fix:

1. Simply copy-and-paste this multi-line command into your shell.  It will create the file `/etc/sysctl.d/android-studio.conf` which will apply the necessary inotify limits upon every system startup:

   ```
    cat << EOF | sudo tee /etc/sysctl.d/android-studio.conf
    # Increase inotify limit, required by Android Studio, https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Inotify+Watches+Limit
    fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 524288
    EOF
   ```
2. Reload your new sysclt configuration file (and all the others):

   ```
    sudo sysctl -p --system
   ```
3. Restart Android Studio.

Here's the IntelliJ documentation for completeness: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Inotify+Watches+Limit

Comment: I'd consider this the most complete answer because of the helpful comment and file name for the new setting instead of appending directly to /etc/sysctl.conf.

Answer (score 8):

If you are running Debian (Ubuntu), RedHat, or another similar Linux distribution, run the following in a terminal:

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

Listen uses inotify by default on Linux to monitor directories for changes. It's not uncommon to encounter a system limit on the number of files you can monitor. For example, Ubuntu Lucid's (64bit) inotify limit is set to 8192.

For further explanations please see [this](https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers)

Answer (score 3):

I am using Ubuntu so this works for me.

1. Go to your terminal and enter

   ```
   $ sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf  "enter your default password"
   ```
2. Add `fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 524288` at the bottom
3. exit terminal and enter

   ```
   $sudo sysctl -p --system
   ```
4. Restart your IDE

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** You may have trouble adding the watches limit line manually to the **sysctl.conf** file located under **/etc** directory. If you try to edit it on the text editor before make running commands as root safer that will let you make necessary adjustments on the file, you may not be allowed to do so.

So, follow these steps to increase the watches limit:

1. type in terminal: `gksudo gedit /etc/sysctl.conf` and enter your password to make administrative changes (note: if you use linux mint mate, use pluma instead of gedit)
2. add the following line at the bottom of that text file. 
   `fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 524288`
3. save the file and run this command to apply the change. `sudo sysctl -p --system`
4. restart your IDE.

Keep enjoying the Android Studio!:)

Comment: Would you know what would the steps be for Arch linux variants? AFAIK they've deprecated sysctl.conf (https://www.archlinux.org/news/deprecation-of-etcsysctlconf/)